# Android viewpager just show data on last fragment view

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm writing a simple app using `fragment` and `viewpager` to display data calling from `webservice`. Problem is `viewpager` creates 3 `fragments` at the first time, but data only view on the last `fragment`.

Here's my activity:

```
public class LineDetailTabs extends FragmentActivity {
//declare some variables here

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_line_detail_tabs);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
    PlaceholderFragment hf = new PlaceholderFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, hf);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(index);
    }
```

This is my adapter, 
 **list_nodep** is a String array contains id of many deparments.
 **count** is number of departments, also number of tabs will be created.

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        noDep = list_nodep[position];

        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        //put some agurments
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

And my fragment here, same layout xml file for all fragments.

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    public static View rootView;

    public static TextView tvHeader;
    public static TextView tvPO;
    public static TextView tvLot;
    // many textviews

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      activity = (LineDetailTabs) getActivity();
      loadData(noDep, date, username, dbIP, dbName, dbUsername, dbPassword);

      rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_line_detail_tabs, container, false);
      tvHeader = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtHeader);
      tvPO = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtPO);
      tvLot = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtLOT);
      // many textviews remaining...

      return rootView;
    }

public static void loadData(String aNoDep, String aDate, String aUsername, String aDbIP, String aDbName, String aDbUser, String aDbPass) {
            RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
            //put params

            invokeWS(params);
     }

public static void invokeWS(final RequestParams params) {

                 AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
                 client.get("http://...", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String response) {
                        try {
                            // JSON Object
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                            // When the JSON response has status boolean value assigned with true

                            JSONArray jArr = obj.getJSONArray("list");

                            // Display info detail on screen
                            obj = jArr.getJSONObject(0);

                            tvHeader.setText = obj.getString("NAME_DEP");
                            tvPO.setText = obj.getString("NO_PO");
                            tvLot.setText = obj.getString("NO_LOT");
                            //set text for all textviews
                    }
                    // When the response returned by REST has Http response code other than '200'
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,
                                          String content) {
                        // When Http response code is '404'
                        if (statusCode == 404) {
                            Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), Constants.ERR_CODE_404, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        // When Http response code is '500'
                        else if (statusCode == 500) {
                            Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), Constants.ERR_CODE_500, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        // When Http response code other than 404, 500
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), Constants.ERR_CODE_, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
         }
    }
```

When debugging my app, I saw `fragment` `onCreateView` run 3 times continuously, and after that cursor jumps to `onSuccess`, so just last `fragment` displayed data. I think I put `loadData()` method or `setText` at the wrong place. Please help.

Comment: I'm confusing here. First you add a `Fragment` at `R.id.container`, then this `R.id.container` turned out to be a `ViewPager`.

Comment: Could you swipe on your `ViewPager` ? Because I think that it couldn't. Your `ViewPager` is now hidden below a `PlaceholderFragment` hf

Comment: I can swipe it, and while I'm swiping, data was loaded corectly in next fragments

Comment: Could you post the full code of `PlaceholderFragment ` ?

Comment: Of course, I updated my question above, all of these code put inside LineDetailTabs activity.

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally I fixed it. That's my mistake, I didn't pass params from activity to fragment.
Just put params here

```
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            noDep = list_nodep[position];
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("NO_DEP", noDep);
            bundle.putString("DATE", date);
            bundle.putString("USERNAME", username);
            bundle.putString("DB_IP", dbIP);
            bundle.putString("DB_NAME", dbName);
            bundle.putString("DB_USER", dbUsername);
            bundle.putString("DB_PASS", dbPassword);
            bundle.putString("SERVER_IP", serverIP);

            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return fragment;
        }
```

Then get these arguments in onCreateView(), and call loadData() method.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_line_detail_tabs, container, false);

        activity = (LineDetailTabs) getActivity();

        noDep = getArguments().getString("NO_DEP");
        date = getArguments().getString("DATE");
        username = getArguments().getString("USERNAME");
        dbIP = getArguments().getString("DB_IP");
        dbName = getArguments().getString("DB_NAME");
        dbUsername = getArguments().getString("DB_USER");
        dbPassword = getArguments().getString("DB_PASS");
        serverIP = getArguments().getString("SERVER_IP");

        loadData(noDep, date, username, dbIP, dbName, dbUsername, dbPassword);

        tvHeader = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtHeader);
        tvPO = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtPO);
        //...

        return rootView;
    }
```